# Android Intent to start Main activity of application

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am trying to start the main activity from inside a BroadcastReceiver.
I dont want to supply the activity class name but to use the action and category for android to figure out the main activity.

It doesnt seem to work.

Sending Code:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent();

startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startIntent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
startIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);        
context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

I get this error:

> Caused bt: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.xyz.abc (has extras) }

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you not want to specify the actual main activity by name?

Comment: @Austyn To use the code in a library for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is not the right way to startActivity.
try this code instead:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);        
context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

Comment: I am having only the context of application instead of MainActivity.class in the library project. How can I start the application's main activity from the library project.?

Comment: @Karthick: there is no problem using application context instead of MainActivity.class, but - if you won't use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag, you'll get an exception in that case, because starting activity from application/Service context requires this flag.

Comment: If I am using context means, How can I use? Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,  (Activity)(PushNotification.mActiveContext)); getting error. I need this in the below link scenario. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843118/launch-android-application-from-library-project

Comment: @Karthick: I've seen your question, and if I understood currectly - I provided a good unswer

Comment: Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(startIntent);

Answer (score 28):

Copy from another topic:

This works since API Level 3 (Android 1.5):

```
private void startMainActivity(Context context) throws NameNotFoundException {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the approved one

Answer (score 2):

Even I had been trying to launch the MainActivity via a library Activity.

And this worked for me:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent();
startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startIntent.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
getApplicationContext().startActivity(startIntent);
```

Make sure you add the activity in your library's manifest!

Comment: And here is exception when I tried the same: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is too late. Might be useful for somone in the future. This helped me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
```