# Launch Android application from Library project

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-library

I am developing the PushNotification for android application in Android Library. I am unable to launch the android application while clicking the push notification message. **I am unable to fetch the android application class in library project for launch in generatePushNotification() method.** The following is the code snippet from library project.

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name); 
 // Here I am getting the android application context as sActiveContext
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,  "need to launch the android application main activity");
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

How can I launch the android application from the Library Project.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your problem is that the activity you wish to provide to the intent is not recognized in the library project, you can use the [packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) to get intent to start activity from this package which have [CATEGORY_LAUNCHER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) attribute

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
```

then you could replace `new Intent(context,  "need to launch the android application main activity")` with `launchIntent`

Comment: The pushnotification message is send to device, while opening the message from the notification, the application have to be launched. This is my requirement. Thanks for the response. I will try this code.

Comment: Digging this answer out, as it's applicable to Xamarin.Android aswell : Intent launchIntent = Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(Application.Context.PackageName);